# Android exception org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG <html>

Tags: android, web-services, exception, android-ksoap2, xmlpullparser

I have been trying to consume a .NET webservice ( HelloWorld method to test first) , using practicly the same code that worked for another webservice .

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld";

    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "HelloWorld";

    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static final String URL = "http://demo.digiparc.com/autocomplete.asmx";

    private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);


        SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet=true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

        HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try{

            aht.call(SOAP_ACTION,envelope);
            Log.i(TAG, "ind");
            SoapPrimitive resultString = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
            System.out.println("Result: "+resultString);
            tv.setText("Status : " + resultString);

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.i(TAG, e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

my first log doesn't show up in the logcat and for the second one I catched the following excpetion :

```
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG <html>@1:6 in java.io.InputStreamReader@45f9a950)
```

Am i doing something wrong ? if anybody who faces the same problem or have any clue about it can help ? my Webservice details are exact .

Answer (score 0):

Its not a problem with android or WebService.
There might be an `app_html.offline` in `APPCODE` which doesnt allow it to run online.
Go to Solution Explorer in C#.
Rightclick and Exclude it from project. :D